# SQL-Server SQLEXPRESS slower then real SQL 2008 Server?

Tags: sql-server

I got my first bigger project with around 150 users at every day since a week.

For my smaller projects like a company homepage with 100 visits each day, I installed the free sqlexpress.
Now it all semms a bit slow and I really try to find out why.
My idea was and my question is: Is the SQLServer Express slower then the SQL Server 2008 full install ?

Answer (score 7):

Note that the limitations of the EXPRESS editions include CPU and memory limitations which might influence performance characteristics.

With the SQL Server EXPRESS 2012 being *["[...]limited to lesser of 1 Socket or 4 cores"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)* and the SQL Server 2008 EXPRESS being [limited to a single CPU with any number of cores](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914278/en-us), the Express editions cannot benefit from multithreading as much as editions without this limit. Also, all versions of EXPRESS editions are limited to a maximum of 1 GB of RAM, meaning that more disk seeks are necessary as soon as the 1 GB is not sufficient to cache the working data set (usually at least all index pages).

Especially the memory limitations surely would make it "slower then the full install" for many applications.

Comment: +1, but it's worth emphasizing that, running on the same set of hardware within those limits, an Express Edition installation will perform the same as a "real" Sql Server installation.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably worth pointing out that its not how many visitors your site gets a week but rather how many visits happen at once and what the load each user generates on the system looks like.

There's a *huge* difference in the database load generated by 150 users spread out over the course of a week (so 21 or 22 visits a day on a 7 day week) who log in, get given a cookie to say they've logged in, and read a new blog post, for example, and 150 users who all hit the site at 9am every single day when work starts, with each one of them needing to run different but complex queries on a massive dataset every hour to track sales or something.

SQL Server Express is only likely to be your problem if you're actually hitting the limits built into SQL Server Express in the same way that a small amount of memory is only a problem on a system if you're doing things that actually require more memory than the system has.